# Oracle 7 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE alternative

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, oracle7

I am working on a **legacy database** which is **Oracle 7** and I want to use the **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** to execute the converted bytes to varchar but I found out the the said function was released on
[Oracle 10g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm#).

Here is my example:

STORED PROCEDURE:

```
create or replace procedure QUERY_EXECUTOR
(
    IN_QUERY_STATEMENT IN LONG RAW
)
AS
BEGIN

    declare CONVERTED_QUERY varchar2(32767); 
    cursor c1 is select IN_QUERY_STATEMENT from dual;
    BEGIN  
        for r2 in c1 loop
        converted_query:=UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(substr(r2.IN_QUERY_STATEMENT,0)); 
        dbms_output.put_line(converted_query);
        end loop;
        execute immediate converted_query; --THIS LINE
    END;

END;
```

Look at **execute immediate** command. When I comment it out. The SP compiled successfully in Oracle 7.

But on Oracle 12g(which we are currently using), the sample code executes just fine.

```
EXEC QUERY_EXECUTOR('53454c45435420312046524f4d204455414c3b');
```

When converted is "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;";

This conversion and execution is for us the best way to handle our current problem so answers will be very much appreciated.

**Question**

Is there a way or alternative solution if we cannot use the said command in Oracle 7?

EDIT:

Found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973003/oracle-dbms-utility-exec-ddl-statement-vs-execute-immediate) which is the other utility of executing literal string commands but it is only for DDL commands.

EDIT 2: **SOLUTION**

The answer by Sir @Wernfried Domscheit did the job for me. I combined the answer with my logic. Although it is not perfect and I think I need to read more of the documentation.

First, it seems that `DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A` is not working in Oracle7.

Then I found [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/System-Packages/DBMSSQLPARSEandDBMSSQLEXECUTE.htm) which having a different `DBMS_SQL.PARSE` method signature. I used it because it says `DBMS_SQL.V7` so it might be Oracle 7 but I really don't know. I need to read the documentations tho.

```
create or replace procedure QUERY_EXECUTOR
(
    IN_QUERY_STATEMENT IN LONG RAW
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
    res INTEGER;
    cur PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    CONVERTED_QUERY varchar2(32767);
    cursor c1 is select IN_QUERY_STATEMENT from dual;
    BEGIN
        for r2 in c1 loop
            converted_query:=UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(substr(r2.IN_QUERY_STATEMENT,0)); 
        end loop;
        DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, converted_query, DBMS_SQL.V7);
        dbms_output.put_line(cur);
        res := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);
        DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);
    END;
END;
```

**PS:**

I'm not a DBA so please if I'm doing something wrong on the solution part, can you give your opinion for much better solution? Very much appreciated the answer.

Comment: This statement/post might help. [exec DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT('create table t1 (id number)');](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973003/oracle-dbms-utility-exec-ddl-statement-vs-execute-immediate/6973293#6973293)

Comment: @ArifSherKhan, I already added that link at "EDIT" section of my post.

Comment: Trivial, but it was Oracle 7 not 7i. Oracle 8i was the first Oracle version to have a letter suffix. Also Oracle 8i was the version which introduced EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to a grateful world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dynamic prior Oracle 8i you have to use the [DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS058) package. Would be like this:

```
DECLARE
   sqlcmd DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A;
   res INTEGER;
   cur PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;

BEGIN

    sqlcmd(1) := 'SELECT 1';
    sqlcmd(sqlcmd.LAST+1) := 'FROM dual';

    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, sqlcmd, sqlcmd.FIRST, sqlcmd.LAST, TRUE, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE); 
    res := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);

END;
```

As far as I remember `DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A` was introduced more recently, perhaps you have to use `DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2_TABLE` or `DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2S`.

In order to get the result from SELECT you have to use `FETCH_ROWS` or `EXECUTE_AND_FETCH` functions, the documentation should help you.

Comment: This actually works for me. I will edit my post and will include the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right your question is: How can I execute dynamic SQL in  Oracle 7.

The pl/sql 'execute' command does not exist in Oracle 7 but the package 'dbms_sql' exists and is described 
[PL/SQL User’s Guide and Reference, Release 2.3, Part No. A32542-1](https://docs.oracle.com/pdf/A32542_1.pdf) on page 5-7 of 'Chapter 5: Interaction with Oracle'
and in [Oracle 7 Server Application Developer's Guide, Release 7.3, Part No. A32536-1](https://docs.oracle.com/pdf/A32536_1.pdf) 'Chapter 10: Using Dynamic SQL', pp 10-1

Comment: Your references help a lot. Thanks!